# ngx-toastr not working inside upload function of Angular 5 service

Tags: angular, angular5, toastr

I am using [ngx-toastr](http://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr) in my Angular 5 project. I have a service in my project which is being used to upload the files to a AWS bucket.

The Problem is I want to use Ngx-toastr inside my service to notify if the file was uploaded successfully or there was some error, but it's not working. Can anyone please help me?

Here is my upload_file_service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';
import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
@Injectable()
export class UploadFileService {

  FOLDER = 'sample';

  constructor(
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private _toastr: ToastrService,
  ) { }

  uploadfile(file) {
    this._toastr.info("uploading" , "Info");  //this one is working fine.
    // this.spinner.show();
    const bucket = new S3(
      {
        accessKeyId: 'sample',
        secretAccessKey: 'sample',
        region: 'sample'
      }
    );

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'bucek_name',
      Key: this.FOLDER + file.name,
      Body: file
    };

    bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
        // this.spinner.hide();
        // this._toastr.error("File Upload Failed, Please Try Again!",  "Error");
        return false;
      }
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data.Location);
      localStorage.setItem('uploaded_data_path' , data.Location);
      // this._toastr.success("File Upload Faild, Please Try Again!" , "Success"); 
      //not working, gives error that success property is not found.
      // this.spinner.hide();   //Not working
     return true; 
    }
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: From my perspective It's not related to call the api, you are calling ToastrService correctly.Is it possible to create an example in https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: See Jeffrey's answer below. That was the reason causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `this` within a `function()` block.

A function creates its own *scope*, with its own `this`, effectively overwriting (replacing) the `UploadFileService`'s `this`.

---

To get around this, you can use the [ES6 arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) functions, which does not create a new scope within the function block:

```
bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    ...
    this._toastr.success("File Upload Faild, Please Try Again!" , Success");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain a little bit why it is happening ? (upvote anyway)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Jeffrey.